# How can i make my recursive function for n choose k use memoization to improve performance?

Tags: c, recursion, memoization

```
long choose(int n, int k) {
    if (k == 0 || k == n) {
        return 1L;
    } else {
        long result = (choose(n-1, k) + choose(n-1, k-1));
        return result;
    }
}
```

This recursive function is very slow when using large numbers. How do I make it use memoization to make it faster?

Comment: You store the result in, for example, an array, check if the value is available and if it is use that, otherwise calculate it and set the value in the array.  Can you bound the size of the problem? Otherwise you need to resize the array.

Comment: This segfaults if n < k.

Comment: You could `malloc` an `(n+1)` by `(n+1)` array of `long` to act as the memoization table. Initialize all entries in the array to 0 (since N choose K is never 0). Pass the array as the third argument to the function. If `array[n][k]` is not 0, then just return `array[n][k]`.

Comment: Is this for an assignment that requires you to practice or use memoization, or do you just want to speed up the routine? Because there is a definite optimization you should make first.

Answer (score 2):

You select a suitable data structure to store your results.  In this case I capped the size of N and K and used an 2d array (note: `choose()` is a fast growing function so it may overflow in practice. ).  If the result is cached return that, otherwise store the new calculation and return that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_N 100
#define MAX_K 100

long choose(int n, int k) {
    if(n < 0 || n > MAX_N) {
       printf("n should be between 0 and %d\n", MAX_N);
       return -1;
    }
    if(k < 0 || k > MAX_K) {
       printf("k should be between 0 and %d\n", MAX_K);
       return -1;
    }
    if(n < k) {
        printf("n should be greater or equal to k\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (k == 0 || k == n) {
        return 1;
    }
    static long memorize[MAX_N+1][MAX_K+1];
    return memorize[n][k] ?
        memorize[n][k] :
        (memorize[n][k] = choose(n-1, k) + choose(n-1, k-1));
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%ld\n", choose(100, 6));
}
```

and example run:

```
1192052400

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.000s
```

I was curious so here is a version that uses a dynamically allocate array.  @autistic points out below `mmap()` and `open_memstream()` as alternatives, `mmap()` in particular can use file backed storage if you need more space than physical memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long choose2(int n, int k, size_t k_len, long *memorize) {
    if (k == 0 || k == n) {
        return 1;
    }
    return memorize[n * k_len + k] ?
        memorize[n * k_len + k] :
        (memorize[n * k_len + k] = choose2(n-1, k, k_len, memorize) + choose2(n-1, k-1, k_len, memorize));
}

long choose(int n, int k) {
    if(n < 0) {
        printf("n must be greater than 0\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if(k < 0) {
        printf("k must be great than 0\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if(n < k) {
        printf("n should be greater or equal to k\n");
        return -1;
    }

    long *memorize = calloc((n+1) * (k+1), sizeof(*memorize));
    if(!memorize) {
        printf("calloc failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    long result = choose2(n, k, k + 1, memorize);
    free(memorize);
    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%ld\n", choose(100, 6));
}
```

It would be a little prettier if memorize was a vla `long (*memorize)[k+1];` which would allow for a more natural `memorize[n][k]` syntax in `choose2()`.

gcc, among others, support nested functions as an extension.  It would be useful here so k_len and memorize would be accessible via the closure of the outer function instead of arguments.

Comment: I was gonna suggest using static storage duration for this, but you beat me to it. Nice answer  A few cleaner alternatives to dynamic storage duration also exist, such as `open_memstream` and `mmap`, the latter of which can be used to memoize into a (potentially huge) file.

Comment: @autistic Thanks.  Updated answer with your suggestions.  I did some benchmark on Linux a while back and if you don't swap pre-allocating memory is about 24% faster than mmap.  If you need more space than memory than mmap (private, file backed, pre-allocate file) is ~33%  faster than writing to a temporary file using 8k block size.